# how to check the space complexity of our code is O(1) or not

Tags: python-3.x, space-complexity

In the question, it is said that we need to write the code in O(1) space complexity I'm getting confused by looking at it .can someone explain the space complexity of this code. If it is not in O(1) is there any way to change it?

> python3

```
from collections import Counter
def duplicates(arr, n): 
    r=[]
    dic=Counter(arr)
    for i in dic:
        if dic[i]>1:
            r.append(i)
    if r:
        r.sort()
        return r
    else:
        r.append(-1)
        return r
```

Comment: I can't answer how to make optimize space without knowing the question that you're trying to solve.

Comment: question is print the elements which are duplicate in the array

Comment: [CS Stackexchange](https://cs.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask these questions

Comment: @anirudh I'd say this is a better fit for SO, actually.

Comment: @anirudh thanks for suggesting CS Stackexchange

Comment: @ggorlen , I guess the user wanted more clear description for `asymptotic notations`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Space complexity is how much space is used asymptotically (when N becomes very large)

O(1) space complexity generally consist of variables and arrays with constant size.

Your code is a O(N) space complexity because the array `r` grows with the size of N.

Comment: so if I don't use the list 'r' space complexity becomes O(1)?

Comment: You mean O(1)? In your code, yes, but you also can't use any array / dictionary that has a non-constant size.

Answer (score 1):

Well if you do not use extra data structures such as an array aside the one in the question then your space complexity is constant O(1) else it might not be.

The question is did you introduce any extra array  of collection to hold your data or results? If no then you solve it in constant space O(1), if yes then it's not constant space.

You have to compute the space complexity base on the extra array you introduced.